# Combine dates and hours in one column

Tags: date, sas

I have two date in datetime format as below:

```
m=14JAN09:08:00:00
n=14JAN09:09:00:00
```

dates are same hours are different.
I need to make it like :

z=mon14jan 8:00am-9:00am

Comment: What are you doing with them?  Do you want to do this for the purpose of doing a `PROC MEANS` or similar and grouping them together?

Comment: I will group them together. I have two variables m and n. Dates are same for all of them. I need to make one variable as z from m and n. dates and hours with (-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are best off decomposing them and recomposing; formats and other methods seem more complex.  I'm not sure where 'mon' comes from - is that 'Monday' (Jan 14, 2009 is not a monday)?

```
z = cat(put(datepart(m),date9.),' ',
        put(timepart(m),timeampm7.),
        put(timepart(n),timeampm7.)
       );
```

Adjust the first part if you want the date format differently of course.  I think the TIMEPART function is not strictly necessary, but I like to include it since it makes clear what you're doing.